# TestNG is not sending the latest emailable-report.html

Tags: selenium, testing, testng, browser-automation

@Aftertest
@AfterSuite
@AfterClass Nothing is helpful in my case when we talk about sending the latest reports in the email.

```
@AfterSuite
    public void statusupdate() throws Exception 
    {
                SendMail.execute();
    }
```

This is what I am doing and every time I am getting an older version of my emailable-report.html as I am struggling with JAVA as well so hopefully someone can help me understanding what is wrong here. My assumption is I am sending the email before the fresh report is generated but have no clue what to do next. Thanks for the patience and your replies.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, welcome to SO. What does SendMail.execute() does and where does it come from?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo it is another class in my framework where the email sending code is written so in my test class in the aftersuite I am calling SendMail's Execute method.

Answer (score 1):

Best you can do is to help yourself with [Listeners](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) for reports, instead of an @afterXxxx method.

So you can do something like:

import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;

```
@Listeners(TestListener.class)
public class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    public void myTest {
        doTest();
    }

}
```

Where your Listener has your SendMail action in the onFinish method:

```
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class TestListener implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        SendMail.execute();
    }

}
```

I hope this does what you need, if not let me know.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo I will try to attempt this also meanwhile temporarily I have managed a solution in which I have removed the email sending method call from @AfterSuite as it was always sending me an old report and now I'm running the SendMail.java after test class execution is getting completed. By running this class separately after test execution is sending me latest copy of emailable-report.html.Thanks again for reaching me Rodrigo :)

Comment: Rodrigo as you said to let you know if listeners do not help so I am adding my comment as I have created listener class and did this 

@Override
 public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
  System.out.println("Test is finished");
  String path="mypath\\emailable-report.html";
  SendMail.execute(path);

 } 
but this still sent me the old report so I just wanted to share it with you that this still consider it a part of test execution. Hope you will get back here for a constructive discussion :) as I am still relying on my old solution of executing sendmail class separately.

Comment: Will take a look between today and tomorrow, but I wonder why is giving you an old report as that method is executed after all tests are finished. Is there something happening after all the tests that is not being reported?

Comment: Sure thanks meanwhile hope this will help you to better understand what is wrong here https://github.com/ahmedbilal-code/TestAutomation/tree/master/NerdBox1 thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to get the latest .html report by implementing extent reports and TestNG listeners in my framework. I am using 7.0 TestNG and its limitation is that it does not update the emailable-report.html so to overcome this problem you will have to implement extent reports where you will always get the latest .html fancy report which you can send through email in onFinish method of your listener class. But before jumping in you have to understand listeners and extent reports rest is given below. Also thanks @rodrigo for giving me a direction :)

public class TestClass{

```
WebDriver driver=null;
public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
 public ExtentReports extent;
 public ExtentTest test;


 public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) throws IOException {
      String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date(0));
      TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
      File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

      // after execution, you could see a folder "FailedTestsScreenshots" under src folder
      String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Screenshots/" + screenshotName + dateName + ".png";
      File finalDestination = new File(destination);
      FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);
      return destination;
     }

@BeforeTest()
@Parameters("browser")
public void setup(String browsername) {
    if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) 
    {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver=new ChromeDriver();

    }
    else if(browsername.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
    {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    }

     htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\test-output\\myReport.html");

      htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Automation Report"); // Tile of report
      htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Functional Testing"); // Name of the report
      htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);

      extent = new ExtentReports();
      extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

      // Passing General information
      extent.setSystemInfo("Host name", "NerdBox");
      extent.setSystemInfo("Environemnt", "QA");
      extent.setSystemInfo("user", "AB");
}



@Test(priority=1,enabled=true)
public void SubmitQuestions() throws Exception {


    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://com/questions");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div")).click();
}
 @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
 public void end(ITestResult result) throws IOException
 {
     test= extent.createTest("The Test is "+result.getName());


        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {

          test.log(Status.FAIL, "TEST CASE FAILED IS " + result.getName()); // to add name in extent report
          test.log(Status.FAIL, "TEST CASE FAILED IS " + result.getThrowable()); // to add error/exception in extent report
          String screenshotPath = NerdboxJobSubmit.getScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
           test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);// adding screen shot
          } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
           test.log(Status.SKIP, "Test Case SKIPPED IS " + result.getName());
          }
          else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
           test.log(Status.PASS, "Test Case PASSED IS " + result.getName());
          }


 }

@AfterTest(alwaysRun=true)
public void flush() throws Exception 
{
    System.out.println("After test");
    extent.flush();

    driver.quit();

}
```